# How do I pass a string to a boto3 function in IPython from a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, boto

I am setting up an environment in Jupyter that allows a user to query their Database Schema from AWS Glue. The Jupyter line magic accepts 2 arguments: the database name, and the table name.

These arguments are then parsed with split(), and separated into two arguments: database, and table.

What would be the best way to pass these to the glue.get_table call? Which accepts 2 argument which I was previously explicitly declaring in the code?

I'm fairly new to Python and may be missing an obvious answer here, but I'm currently passing them as string variables.

@line_magic('describe')
def describe(self, line, local_ns = None):

```
database = line.split(" ")[0]
view     = line.split(" ")[1]

glue = boto3.client('glue', region_name=ec2_metadata.region)        
response = glue.get_table(DatabaseName='%s', Name='%s' % (database, view))
```

I am expecting to see these values passed into boto as if I were to write them in myself, but I am seeing

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

being thrown on the glue.get_table() function

Comment: you are passing two parameters to the function `get_table()`

- first a string`'%s'` as a parameter `DatabaseName`
- second a a construct `'%s' % (database, view)` as a parameter `Name` into the same function and that's where the error happens - you are trying to squeeze two variables into one `%s` placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
response = glue.get_table(DatabaseName=database, Name=view)
```

Comment: Wow, somehow this was so obvious I didn't think it would even work. But it did! How in this instance am I able to pass a variable directly like that? Again, I'm very very new to Python.

Comment: Because database and view are both already strings. You could also do it your way with a little correction:
`response = glue.get_table(DatabaseName='%s' % (database), Name='%s' % (view))`
But theres no need for that. Remember, in python, everything is simple:)

Comment: Awesome, somehow that messy way still makes sense to me! But I'm excited to come to grips with the small features like this that make Python such a pleasure to work with. Thank for your help! :)